# javascript map.set not working when trying to add new property to redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a list of maps like the following in my redux state

```
[
   {
       "id": "id1",
       "code": "code0"
   },
   {
       "id": "id2",
       "code": "code1"
   }
]
```

I am unable to add a new property to the above list of maps. Below is the code which I use to add a new property to the map

```
case SET_NEW_PROPERTY: {
   const a = currentState.get('reduxstate')
   a.forEach((mapObj, index) => {
      mapObj.set('newproperty', 'value')
   }
   return currentState.set('reduxstate', a)
}
```

I am not sure why the set is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure they are maps and not just regular objects?

Comment: Yes it is a map and I tried without return also, but no luck.

Comment: The code posted should work. Can you provide more context? How is the array populated? How is the result of the above code used?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `plain object` in redux store, In this case, add new property to `Map` doesn't changed state, it's same reference to `Map`.

When connect to Pure React Component, cause props didn't changed, UI will not update.

And mention, when try to add property to `plain object` in reducer, you should return new object, or you can use `combineReducers`, it will automatic return new object when any property value changed.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: You can use the spread operator and map. something like this

```
state = [
          {
             "id": "id1",
             "code": "code0"
          },
          {
             "id": "id2",
             "code": "code1"
          }
        ];
```

then simply add new object like this

```
[
  ...state,
    {
      "id": "id3",
      "code": "code3"
    }
]
```

UPDATE: However, if you want to add a new property to the map then you can do this.

```
const newState = state.map( item => ({ ...item,  "newProperty": "newvalue",  }));
```

Comment: He is not trying to add new objects (maps really) to the array. He is trying to add a new property to all the existing maps.

Comment: OP is not asking for a new entry in the array. He is asking for a new key in each entry.